# Polish Letters in Gnuplot, UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: encoding, gnuplot

I have a CSV file with a data, and I need to plot a histogram (bars actually) using the data from given file. However, labels at axis X need to have Polish letters, for instance `ąęćżźśłóń` (or, uppercase, ĄĘĆŻŹŚŁÓŃ). I have already set the encoding with `set encoding iso_8859_1` but still, the result does not look like what I want:

[image]

Here is my gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set encoding iso_8859_1 
set datafile separator "\t"
set termoption enhanced

set terminal postscript eps size 5.5, 5.62 enhanced color font 'Verdana,20' linewidth 2
set output '2008.eps'
unset key 

set xtics nomirror rotate by -45 scale 0 font ",15"
set style data histogram
set boxwidth 0.2
set grid y
set yrange [        * : 20000]
set style fill solid border
plot '2008.csv' using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes linecolor rgb "#00FF00", \
     ''          using 0:2:2 with labels center offset 0,1 notitle
```

And my data file:

```
Województwo Suma
Dolnośląskie    4997    4997
Kujawsko-Pomorskie  10710   10710
Lubelskie   8978    8978
Lubuskie    4631    4631
Łódzkie 12609   12609
```

The question is: what do I need to do to have Polish letters on axis X, and in a plot title (which is not available here, but I would like to add it later)? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the data file has the right encoding?

Comment: @CodingLambdas: I think so. I used `iconv -t UTF-8 data.csv > 2008.csv` before plotting

Comment: Then you may set the encoding to `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-....`. (Although I am no expert in gnuplot, I didn't even use this at any time in my life)

Comment: @CodingLambdas: OK, I understand. However, using your advice, it gives me not something like this: http://s32.postimg.org/6qshmuswl/2008.png, which basically is still not what I need.

Comment: Sorry... I think I can't help. As I said, I've *nothing* to do with gnuplot.

Comment: Does `set locale "pl_PL"; set encoding locale` helps?

Comment: @bibi: `set locale "pl_PL" "./histogram.plt", line 4: Locale not available`

Comment: I meant in the gnuplot script

Comment: @bibi: Of course, I modified the script itself, but this is the output I got after running the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use UTF-8. Here's what I did:

```
set terminal epscairo enhanced color dashed rounded size 5.5, 5.62

set encoding utf8
set output '2008.eps'

unset key
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45 scale 0 font ",15"
set style data histogram
set boxwidth 0.2
set grid y
set yrange [*:20000]
set style fill solid border
plot '2008.csv' using 2:xticlabels(1) with boxes linecolor rgb "#00FF00", \
'' using 0:2:2 with labels center offset 0,1 notitle
```

(I copied the data from your question, which is in UTF-8 format but doesn't contain `tab` characters, so I didn't use `set datafile separator "\t"`.)

This gave me the following result.

[image: Output of above script]

I'm using the `epscairo` terminal because it uses the `pango` library for rendering text which is based on UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it helped! :)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) In case you do not know of it, have a look at [gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/) and the [not-so-FAQ](http://security.riit.tsinghua.edu.cn/~bhyang/ref/gnuplot/index-e.html). The [palletes repository](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes) might also be worth visiting.